# Duplicate User login?

Tags: command-line, login, users

I am testing my new (dual boot) Ubuntu install. When playing with basic terminal commands I noticed that i was logged in (or something to that effect) twice! Here are my commands and the terminal results.

```
~$ who
karsus   :0           2016-01-27 21:24 (:0)
karsus   pts/9        2016-01-27 21:24 (:0)
~$ w
21:26:46 up 3 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.28, 0.34, 0.15
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
karsus   :0       :0               21:24   ?xdm?  55.54s  0.14s init --user
karsus   pts/9    :0               21:24    1.00s  0.03s  0.00s w
~$
```

Did I do something wrong? When I first saw this I restarted my laptop and went to the terminal straight after log in. Then I got the results posted above.

Is that normal? - If so what does it mean?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where it was answered - I was googling the who/w commands - didn't realize users would be the same.